# How to take a session variable in Flask, and display it in a HTML Navbar and have it as a dropdown button?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

[[image]]This is the code for the navbar.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvKGW.png)[This is the code for the login function]I already have a nav bar created and I had a working solution when I wasnt using sessions in Flask. Now I am using sessions. I take a successful user login to a server and I want to display that username on other pages in a navbar. If possible I also want to turn that displayed variable into a dropdown that links to other pages. Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Hopefully that helps, sorry im very new to Flask, HTML and Stack Overflow. Wish me luck!

Answer (score 3):

So after an excruciating ammout of digging, i found the answer.
You dont need to pass the session fucntion to anything. All you have to do is call the session variable. {{session.##whateveryounamesyoursessionvariable##}} Thanks to everyone. Sorry for waisting everyones time.

Comment: The excruciating amount of time you spent digging helped me spend no time to find the answer - thanks!